# Do weapon mods last one match?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

In Mass Effect 3 Multiplayer you get one match items (whether you use or not) and items that don't disappear. Are weapon mods (e.g. pistol scopes) one match items?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Weapon mods are a permanent  item. Some only work with certain weapons/types of weapons, which may make it seem like they disappeared, but they cannot be expended by any means and are yours unless you decide to delete/get rid of them.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

No, there are not!
Once you get them, you'll keep them forever, even if you reset your character.

(you can even share it between your differents characters)